# Добавление библиотек в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Мне необходимо добавить библиотеки, скачанные с интернета, которые хранятся в форме каталогов, в проект. Делаю это следующим образом: `File->Project Structure->Dependencies->+->Jar or directories.` Однако почему-то, когда добавляю нужный каталог, получается следующее:
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема, что я не так делаю?

Comment: Возможно получится если поместить ваши библиотеки в src, как исходники?

Comment: @Sergei Mikhailovskii Вот [тут](https://javadevblog.com/kak-dobavit-biblioteku-jar-fajl-v-proekt-intellij-idea.html) почитай.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh, у меня не в jar формате, а классы, которые хранятся в каталогах

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii Если за 20 часов никто не ответил, то не мне одному видимо не совсем понятен вопрос. Что за библиотеки? Откуда скачаны? Что за проект делаешь? :)

Comment: .zip подойдёт вместо .jar если вы скачивали и разархивировали в каталоги с классами

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh да, согласен, не совсем правильно вопрос задал. Уже даже походу понял свою ошибку: библиотеку скачивал отсюда https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java (скачал весь репозиторий). Но видимо я не прав, и это не совсем библиотека